# Create a Multidimensional Array of GameObjects and floats

Tags: c#, list, hashtable, unity-game-engine

I would like to create an array that contains a GameObject and a corresponding float.

I am trying to give each enemy the ability to drop an item when they die. That item will be one of the GameObjects and the float is the probability it will be dropped.

So I created this Class:

```
public class ItemToDrop : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject itemToDrop;
    public float probability;
}
```

And tried using it in my Enemy class:

```
[SerializeField]
    private List<ItemToDrop> items;
```

I also tried just doing

```
Hastable<GameObject, float> items;
```

but it doesn't like being told what objects it should hold.

But that doesn't work. I tried ArrayList etc..

Is there a way to create a List, Hashtable (or other container) in this fashion?

Comment: List<ItemToDrop> should work

Comment: i have no previous experience in Unity but does unity supports list at all ??  also i am not understanding why you tried using hastable

Comment: @RJ- Unity supports List<T> just fine, I'm using them in my own project. I don't know what the problem here is though.

Comment: @Draco18s are you able to create similar file  in a simple unity project ?

Comment: [System.Serializable] Have you tried using it above your  "ItemToDrop" class? I use it to display custom class in editor with List<custom class> and add[SerializeField] tag to the list. Also let me understand your question you want to assign the gameobjects and float values in editor? Am i correct?

Comment: @RJ- I could, if I knew what you were trying to achieve. You can't serialize GameObjects, you have to serialize enough information *about* them to recreate them (i.e. name of prefab, any values set, etc). E.g. [this list](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/CraftingManager.cs#L19) is not serialized, [this list is](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/QuestManager.cs#L22). [continued...]

Comment: And while the `Quest` object does have [a GameObject field](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/quests/Quest.cs#L82), that field [is not serialized](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/quests/Quest.cs#L652). Instead it's [set during the (re)creation of the interface](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/QuestManager.cs#L105-L107), as the GameObject is only a fast-reference to the on-screen object (to avoid `GameObject.Find()` calls).

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are wanting to assign your class's variables from the inspector.
I tried out this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ItemToDrop :System.Object {
    public GameObject itemToDrop;
    public float probability;
}
```

And got the following output in inspector.
[image]